# Cannot delete and update items in my shopping cart something wrong with sessions

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I have shopping cart, and when I add items into the cart and when I want to change the quantity or to delete any of the items it gives me empty cart. Here is the code for the shopping cart, at the beginning:

Edited:

```
<?php 
session_start();
require "C:/xampp/...../DButils.php";
require "C:/xampp/..../functions.php";
$msg = '';
if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && isset($_REQUEST['pid'])>0)
 {
    remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command'] == 'clear'){
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command'] == 'update'){
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
        if($q>0 && $q<=999){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
        }
        else{
            $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999';
        }
    }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: First of all isset($_REQUEST['command']) can never be equal clear or  update, the result is true or false. remove the isset, then you may encounter other errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `isset()` function correctly. That will return a boolean value true or false, not a string of the value. What you probably intend to do is:

```
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command'] == 'clear'){
```

...and...

```
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command'] == 'update'){
```

Without those changes, you will never be able to execute those code blocks because true/false will NEVER equal "clear" or "update".

Comment: this only changed the ability to update the cart, but if I want to remove one item I can't. where can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='add' && $_REQUEST['productid']>0)
{
    remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
}
```

It looks like you're trying to remove the product when you want to be adding one.

Also, as @cillosis mentioned

```
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='update'){
```

will ALWAYS evaluate to false. This is because isset() only ever returns a BOOLEAN value (true, false, 1, 0) and you're evaluation the condition: "If 'true/false' equals 'update'" and since true and false are both not equal to the string 'update' the test will fail every time.

It may make it easier to give you answer to your question if you update the code in your question to remove the errors as they're pointed out. As it's currently written it is fairly hard to decipher.

Comment: I edited the code above, but now the update and clear the cart are not working.

Comment: Are you calling session_start() everywhere you try to access $_SESSION? You have to session_start() in each PHP script you use that calls the $_SESSION super-global. PHP won't warn, notice, or error if you have try accessing $_SESSION but shows it only as an empty variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['id']>0){
 remove_product($_REQUEST['id']);
 }
 else if($_REQUEST['command']=='clear'){
 unset($_SESSION['cart']);
 }
 else if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
 $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
 for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
 $id=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['id'];
 q=intval($_REQUEST['qty'.$id]);
 if($q>0 && $q<=999){
 $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
 }
 else{
 $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999';
 }
 }
 }
```

In Form Button Should Be Like This

```
 <a href="javascript:del(<?php echo $id?>)">
 <input type="button" class="button5" value="Remove" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i know that server language(php) do not understand that directory given,
Try to have a valid directory like
require `projectName/functions.php;` hope it will help too.